# SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake Acknowledgement Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2012, iis-8

We have a production website with a mixture of classic ASP, inline .Net and compiled .Net that talks to a SQL Server instance where both are VMs on the same physical box and everything there works great. In order to do some testing with new features I created a QA version of the site and have it setup to connect to a database on a VM hosted on another physical server. They are different networks (DMZ/internal), but all in the same rack on gigabit so connection speeds shouldn't be an issue.

The problem we're running into is the QA version will work for a bit and then suddenly dies until I restart the app pool and the site. It's not a load issue because it's just me and two other people testing this process and I've confirmed the server where the QA database is at doesn't have a resource issue (16GB RAM, 3.2GB in use and processor utilization hovers in the 2% range). The specific error (shown below) occurs with all variants of the pages - classic ASP, inline .Net and the compiled .Net pages. Based on all the research I've done, I keep getting pointed back to it being a firewall issue, but we even opened all ports between the two servers and it still happens. The strangest part is when we enable tracing on our ASA (5515-X), it sees hardly any traffic and sometimes the site kicks back that error immediately while other times it takes 30+ seconds. The pages in question aren't doing any intense lookups (one page that dies is grabbing a total of about 60 records) as well. Here is the full error/stack trace:

```
  [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

  [SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21008; handshake=12; ]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6749670
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error) +817
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync() +344
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket() +48
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +693
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6777754
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6778255
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +878
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6781425
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2105
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1089
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6785863
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

I'd show a code block, but since all pages start dying once one does it wouldn't do much good. This all works great in production so the only difference is that the VMs are on different physical hosts, but given that it's all new hardware there's no reason this should have issues.

I've also come across multiple things on here where using `exec sp_updatestats` and `dbcc freeproccache`, however neither of those seemed to make a difference.

I'm completely lost so any suggestions?

Comment: You say you've opened all ports, what is your port configuration and have you removed software firewalls from the servers?

Comment: Default ports (1433) and no software firewalls in place. I still don't think it's a firewall thing because it works great, then dies with zero changes in between - it just stops. With firewall issues, it wouldn't be intermittent like that I wouldn't think. It'd either work or not.

Comment: Sorry thought you said it worked in production just not on dev box, must have mis-read your question. If it's intermittent then it won't be a port / firewall issue like you have already pointed out.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm at a complete loss here.

Comment: Sorry but nothing springs to mind. Maybe try setting a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) that way you might get some more interest in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem with SQL Express 2014, turned out to be a Windows Firewall problem, some of our Servers have SQL 2005/2008 on them, all with the Windows Firewall disabled.

Made the change on my PC and it worked perfectly afterwards!

Thanks

Brendan

Answer (score 6):

I ran into an issue similar to this myself a few months ago.

For me, enabling TCP/IP for both IPV4 and IPV6 in SQL Server Configuration manager fixed the issue. I have also seen this occur even when IPV6 is not installed. Oddly enough, I've even experienced this behavior even when I only specify IPV4 addresses?!

Comment: I had experienced hand shake error. One day connection was blocked. After checking IPV6, connection was made.  Thank you!

Comment: @KyungMin My pleasure, Kyung. I'm glad I could help! :)

Comment: this is complete describe soulution http://stackoverflow.com/a/15488923/308578

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem/error msg. For me, it's the firewall settings on server. Make sure TCP port 1433 is open for incoming traffic.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error after firewall enable. 
I did add ports to firewall look at [enable sqlserver port](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968872) 
then again I got that error.

Enable both Named Pipes and TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager , you can find it in:

Startmenu> allprogram > microsoft sql server > configuration tools.