# Entity Framework fails to open connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, signalr, asp.net-identity-2

There are Windows service with a self-hosted SignalR application.

Service:

```
using (var webApp = WebApp.Start(url))
{
    _logger.Info($"SignalR running on: {url}");

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    CookieName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieName"],
    CookieDomain = cookieDomain,
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    Provider = new AuctionCookieAuthenticationProvider()
};

app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration() { EnableDetailedErrors = true, });
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new SignalRUserIdProvider());
```

When the client connects the hub everything goes well, but when the number of active connections reaches 100-150, I get the following error:

> Exception during request processing.
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=5; handshake=14986;
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass4.<b__3>d__6.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<EnsureConnectionAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__25`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SecurityStampValidator.<>c__DisplayClass2`3.<b__1>d__4.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__2.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.d__5.MoveNext()

Windows Firewall is off. As I follow the instructions there:

- [SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake Acknowledgement Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566795/sql-server-pre-login-handshake-acknowledgement-error)
- [Connection to SQL Server Works Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488922/connection-to-sql-server-works-sometimes)

I found this question: [SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340644/sql-server-pre-login-handshake), but I did not understand where I should call `SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);` in EF.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=DTLN-AUC-SQL.dtln-cislink.lan;Initial Catalog=Auction2013;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=20000
```

Comment: have you benchmark your all db query? possible some query running long time and makes connection time out.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488922/connection-to-sql-server-works-sometimes#15488923

Comment: @GhostTW, the heaviest query takes 2 seconds and is not often performed. The average time to complete other queries is 500 ms.

Comment: @Hackerman, as was written above, I have already followed the instructions from this answer. In addition, the servers do not have the IPv6 protocol installed

Comment: Special characters? Visible or invisible?