# New User on SQL Server cannot connect from remote SSMS client

Tags: sql-server

I set up the new user using guidelines from http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2014/tutorial/sql_server_user_logins.cfm

I get the following pop up error on the client when connecting...

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=1834;
>   handshake=4041;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566795/sql-server-pre-login-handshake-acknowledgement-error

Comment: There used to be 'Allow Remote Connections' checkbox on 2012: http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/