# I am getting Connection TIME OUT Error When Users Access .net Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.
This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a firewall issue. Firewall seems to be blocking connection to sql server for port 1433. You will need to add a rule to allow connection on this port.

You can find more on this here: [SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake Acknowledgement Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566795/sql-server-pre-login-handshake-acknowledgement-error)

Comment: After 2 Months R &D on Web Server And SQL SERVER  I Got Solution For The Connection pool Error
    
    I Have Found the Solution for Connection Pooling in ASP.NET and MVC as WELL,
    Set the WEB SERVER Settings Properly  Go The Web Server Select the Connection Pool , select the Application Pool then , Select Which  site You are facing, Then Right Click on The Pool Name -->Select Adv Settings Set the Max Worker Processors "1" to 6000 .Then You never Face This Problem. in my Case Set Max Worker Processors  to 6000