# Sql Exception cant solve and run the program

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, ado.net

This is My Asp.net CodeBehindFile.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Data; 
namespace binding 
{ 
public partial class dataFromTable : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
stringstr=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]
.ConnectionString; 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
 { 
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select ID,CityID,CityName,Country from  
City", con);        
con.Open();
DropDownList1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader(); 
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CityName"; 
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CityID"; DropDownList1.DataBind(); }

} 
} 
}
```

It shows 2 Errors
First one is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.

Second Error is:

> connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to
>   connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=26285;
>   handshake=912;

Comment: This may well be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488922/connection-to-sql-server-works-sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill an offline `DataTable` which you can use as `DataSource` for your `DropDownList`. Also,  use the `using`-statement for objects implementing `IDisposable`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable tblCities = new DataTable();
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        using (var com = new SqlCommand("Select ID,CityID,CityName,Country from City", con))
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
            da.Fill(tblCities); // you dont need to open/close the connection with Fill

        DropDownList1.DataSource = tblCities;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CityName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CityID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Don't  databind it on every postback, otherwise it prevents events and cancels the selection. Use the `!IsPostBack`-check as i've done above..

Comment: Dear tim, This Code "SqlDataAdapter" is not working.Again it shows the same error

Comment: Dear Tim,Please give another Solution.I am using visual studio2013 for web and sqlserver 2014 .

Comment: Please anybody answer my question.