# ssms connection timeout expired pre-login handshake error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am unable to connect to SQL Server using SSMS 2014/2012. But able to connect successfully using DBVisualizer.

Getting below error:

> Connecton Timeout Expired. The tmeout period elapsed while attempting
>   to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be
>   because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to
>   respond back in tme. The duraton spent While attempting to connect to
>   this server  vvas - [Pre-Login] initializaton=18096; handshake=14271;
>   (Microsoft SQL Server)

I have tried the below solutions, but still no luck:

`telnet serverip 1433` - works fine from my computer

[Connection to SQL Server Works Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488922/connection-to-sql-server-works-sometimes) - To try this, I installed SQLServerAdvancedServices and then, for each listed IP address, set Active and Enabled to Yes. When I install just SSMS, these options don't even show up.

What else can I try here to get it working? Thanks in advance.