# Connection timeout on azure sql

Tags: sql-server, azure

Ceased to operate a website in Azure, with the events of the application only one error

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgment. This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to
>   connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization = 21218;
>   handshake = 7240;

Apparently, App Service can not connect to the database. But:

Yesterday it is normally connected
Settings does not change, just the night there was an error (the site is not even used)
All the other instruments (SQL server management studio, power bi, SQL explorer) connected to the base without problems.
How to determine the cause of failure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've restarted your WebApp?  There could also be an issue with leaking/non-closing connections.

Overall, you could be running into a number of throttling issues or your DB is overloaded.  I'd increase the tier of the database, ensure you can connect and start looking into queries that are taking the most utilization, or database size, or number of connections... Tons of folks use our service called [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) to monitor their SQL Azure databases and get deeper insight into their health, but your DB has to be up for this to happen

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Connection to SQL Server Works Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488922/connection-to-sql-server-works-sometimes) I think you have same issue.Hope it will help to solve this.