# Connection Timeout Expired When there are many requests simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a .Net Application(REST API) which accesses SQL Server Database. Sometimes When there are many API requests at the same time, I get Connection Timeout exception due to which all the request fails. This is not always the case and happens only when there are many requests hitting the server at the same time.

Exception Details:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout
>   Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the
>   pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the
>   pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in
>   time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server
>   was - [Pre-Login] initialization=4; handshake=14992;  --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out.

Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to consider the way you are connecting to SQL Server. Could you provide more information on how you connect to the database?

Comment: in this case may be few reasone.
1. You are using express sql server.
2. Dead lock between your queries. 
3. Queries executed more then standart timeout- 30 sec

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets might be useful.  Also profile your SQL server requests - might occur multiple selects on non indexed column data e.t.c. if you write data - then various locks initiated ....

Comment: >>>the pre-login handshake failed<<< This means that the connection was not established at all. It's not runaway query/blocking/deadlocking, the query submitted just have no chance to be executed as the CONNECTION ITSELF FAILED

Answer (score 0):

From this (upvoted) comment

> in this case may be few reasons:
>   1. You are using SQL Server Express
>   2. Dead lock between your queries
>   3. Queries executed more then standard timeout- 30 sec

You should first exclude N1, as the server Edition has nothing to do with connection timeout that is imposted by `client`

Then exclude N2 as the deadlocks are resolved automatically by server deadlock monitor that controls for deadlocks every 5 seconds or even less when the deadlocks are frequent.

Than exclude N3 as `connection timeout` has nothing to do with `execution timeout`. And your timeout is `CONNECTION` timeout.

You should increase `connection timeout` on your client or troubleshoot your server, what happens there that your server becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't agree with your answer.
Express edition has limits, which can affect performance. 
Next, deadlock. User can lock one or more tables. Sorry, but, we didn't seen any queries or tables and we can write only supposition.
And last, the result of the previous reasons: slowly requests execution (more than standard connection timeout -30 sec), and connection has closed without receiving an answer

Comment: >>>connection has closed without receiving an answer<<< means Execution timeout. But the connection that was not established at all is CONNECTION timeout. The error says clearly "**Connection** Timeout Expired" This means that your query did not ever start. You just was not connected to server at all. For example, if the server is down, or your connection string is wrong, you also has CONNECTION timeout.

Comment: Ok. It's true. Thanx. Sam has wrote " When there are many API requests at the same time, I get Connection Timeout exception". I wrote only supposition.

Comment: Maybe answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488922/connection-to-sql-server-works-sometimes

Comment: The second answer from the lik you posted suggests the same as my answer: "to add a connection timeout of 30 seconds into the connection string". As the first attempt connection timeout should be increased

Comment: Default connection timeout 15 sec. It's a lot. More than 15 seconds wait for answer? I think must be better solution. We doesn't live in the 20th century))))))

Comment: Following you it seems that 24 persons who upvoted that answers were dinosaurs

Comment: No. It's fix this problem but create new with performance. I said that solution must be more complex. And need to search reason of such issue.

Comment: ...And the cause may be even the network problems, but they are surely NOT in your list

Comment: Okey. Yes, maybe, i wrote not perfect comment, but it wasn't "answer" and i wrote only supposition. And we both don't know what is the real reason of this issue. I think this discussion are finished. Your answer is more look like as correct

Comment: @KreminT I just wanted to emphasize that the problem is in CONNECTION timeout, not in an EXECUTION timeout, and your comment has a list of possible cause of EXECUTION timeout. The CONNECTION timeout can be caused by network problems or wrong connectivity settings, it's something that not permits you to COnNECT. It can be even firewall, but it's not the case when "This is not always the case and happens only when there are many requests"

Comment: Please, read Sam's question. I have read " Sometimes When there are many API requests at the same time, I get Connection Timeout exception due to which all the request fails." And for my answer please read it https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9aa57b92-9c51-41ef-b30a-ce3c971dea31/sql-express-timeout?forum=sqlexpress